# How to get something as Ltrim(object,number) on sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, trim

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
select product, quantity from datainformation
```

this table returns:

```
product quantity
1        10
2        30
4        23
191      10
900       1
1234      5
12345     2
```

1. two columns are int.
2. table could to have N records

I need to get 2 Strings for EVERY 50 records. My question is how to get these strings:

```
stringproducts='1    2    4    191  900  1234 12345'
stringquantity='10   30   23   10   1    5    2    '
```

Now I need these strings for every 50 records so, for example, if I have 51 records I need
my second "block" to have the last product and the last quantity.

In another language I could use `ltrim(cad,5)`. How would I do this in SQL?

Can I use stuff for this? Or do I need a loop and concatenate them 1 for 1?
I believe with a stuff it could be easier (maybe a stuff inside a loop but it would be easier a loop for every record)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177827.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF()`:

```
select 
  stuff((
        select ' ' + cast(product as char(10))
        from datainformation
        for XML path('')),1,1,'') as products,
 stuff((
        select ' ' + cast(quantity as char(10))
        from datainformation
        for XML path('')),1,1,'') as quantity
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db1ed/12)

Answer (score 0):

If you cast it as CHAR(5), it will have the trailing spaces to make up a 5-char block for your pretty formatted, concatenated string.

```
declare @t table (product int, quantity int);
insert @t select
1        ,10 union all select
2        ,30 union all select
4        ,23 union all select
191      ,10 union all select
900      , 1 union all select
1234     , 5 union all select
12345    , 2;

declare @products varchar(max);
declare @quantity varchar(max);

select @products = coalesce(@products,'')
                 + cast(product as char(5)),
       @quantity = coalesce(@quantity,'')
                 + cast(quantity as char(5))
from @t
order by product

select @products, @quantity
```